# Node.js vs Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js

Which one is more futureproof at this point?
Which one is better for creating simple web apps in smallest time?
This also might be a question of JS vs Ruby, what do you think of this?

What are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: I also would love to know the answer to this. Overall, I would say I prefer ruby as a language but nodejs has it's strong sides.

Comment: Why do you prefer ruby?

Comment: These tools are for slightly different (while close) purposes. Comparisons would imply expression of specific opinions, which is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: I see.. hm. The question was asked to compare the products, or possible outcomes, actually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you do more google on this topic because it is a very general topic. However these articles offer some comprehensive comparisons:

1. http://ilikekillnerds.com/2014/07/should-i-use-ruby-on-rails-or-node-js-for-my-next-projectstartup/
2. http://fabianosoriani.wordpress.com/2011/09/11/when-to-ruby-on-rails-when-to-node-js/